# Calculation in join isn't working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this join:

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET Change = isnull(tab2.Value,0) - tab1.Value 
FROM 
    (SELECT Date,ID,ID,FileName,Value FROM Table_Name WHERE FileName = 'x' AND Date = '2012-05-17') tab1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT Date,ID,TradeID,FileName,Value FROM Table_Name WHERE FileName = 'x' AND Date = '2012-05-18')  tab2 
ON tab1.FileName = tab2.FileName AND 
tab1.ID = tab2.ID  AND 
tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

As you can see, it is a left outer join. However, when I have data for May 17th and none for May 18th, the value inserted should be -17th.Value (because the general calculation is 18th.Value - 17th.Value and 18th.Value would be zero).

If I put a select statement just below the insert part (for debugging) this shows correctly, however, when I remove the SELECT statement and do the calculation in the SET part, it does not work. I end up with values for Change of null, where a match for the 18th of May could not be found.

EDIT: I should add I am unsure whether I need LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN. I wish to return all rows from tab1 and if it does not exist in tab2 the Change value should be -tab1.Value, as opposed to tab2.Value - tab1.Value.

Comment: You are doing an ISNULL check on the first value not the second, could this be an issue?

Comment: @PaulMcCowat `EXISTS` wouldn't allow him to pull the value back from that table.  He won't have `NULL` in the second field since it's the source table not the `JOIN`ed  table

Comment: What values are you getting for the calculation where `tab2.value` is `NULL`?

Comment: @JNK, if I insert another level of SELECT below the 'SET' (for debugging) and perform the calculation in this extra SELECT statement I get 0 instead of null- as I would like. However, when I remove the select and shift the calculation and null check to the SET statement it goes wrong.

Comment: @user1107474 And where is `Table_Name` in all this?

Comment: Table_Name is the table where all the data originates from? I am joining on the same table because different rows represent different time data.

Comment: @user1107474 You have to have table_name in your `FROM` clause though for it to actually work...

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is shorthand for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, at least in DB2, and I believe every other major RDBMS too (something that major?).

Comment: Erm does someone care to elaborate why this should be closed?

Comment: @X-Zero, thanks for that I was beginning to worry!

Comment: @JNK, I do have it though? Its embedded within a SELECT? Or are you saying I cannot embed like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 doesn't allow `UPDATE`s (or `DELETE`s) to contain any joins in the main table-reference clause, which to my mind prevents certain types of issues.  Yes, I'm aware you're on SQL Server, which is why you're attempting this - I just tend to write things with DB2 constraints in mind, is all.

Assuming that you want to update rows for the 17th, I believe the following should work.  Otherwise, please specify which rows you actually want updated.

```
UPDATE Table_Name 
SET change = -value + COALESCE((SELECT nxt.value
                                FROM Table_Name nxt
                                WHERE nxt.fileName = table_name.fileName
                                AND nxt.id = table_name.id
                                AND nxt.scenarioId = table_name.scenarioId
                                AND nxt.cobDate = '2012-05-18'), 0)
WHERE fileName = 'GBP.csv'
AND cobDate = '2012-05-17'
```

---

**EDIT:**
Corrected errors for above.

However... from the sound of things, you may be attempting to update rows that *don't exist*; specifically, the 'result needs to entered for the 18th'.  If what you're doing is attempting to update those rows for the 18th that do exist, or insert them if they do not, you're going to need two statements (or maybe a `MERGE`?  Except I don't have them in my version, so I can't help you with that):

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET change = value - COALESCE((SELECT prev.value
                               FROM Table_Name prev
                               WHERE prev.fileName = table_name.fileName
                               AND prev.id = table_name.id
                               AND prev.scenarioId = table_name.scenarioId
                               AND prev.cobDate = '2012-05-17'), 0)
WHERE fileName = 'GBP.csv'
AND cobDate = '2012-05-18';

INSERT INTO Table_Name (id, scenarioId, fileName, cobDate, value, change) 
                        SELECT id, scenarioId, fileName, '2012-05-18', 0, -value
                        FROM Table_Name
                        WHERE fileName = 'GBP.csv'
                        AND cobDate = '2012-05-17'
                        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                                        FROM Table_Name nxt
                                        WHERE nxt.fileName = table_name.filename
                                        AND nxt.id = table_name.id
                                        AND nxt.scenarioId = table_name.scenarioId
                                        AND nxt.cobDate = '2012-05-18');
```

You **MUST** run them *in that order*.
You **MUST ALSO** *lock the table* for the combined run of *both* statements, have some other method to ensure that no rows containing relevant data are modified (`INSERT`ed, `UPDATE`d, `DELETE`d), or be able to tell which rows were *not* touched.

If this isn't the behavior you want, please modify your question to be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Z-Zero, there appears to be a small problem with the syntax 'as origin' and the ',0)' (the latter could be a consequence of the former error)?

Comment: Regarding the errors, it was a missing bracket after COALESCE and I couldnt get the 'as origin' to work. I replaced "origin." this with "Table_Name."

Comment: I dont think this is quite what I am looking for. The result of the subtraction actually needs to be entered for the 18th and the emphasis is on the LEFT JOIN. I tried editing your SQL but I couldnt get it to do that :s (probably my mistake!)